# pattern match: switch case when for char in java 21

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I tried Java's Pattern Matching features, especially `case when`

I got an error and anyone can help me solve it?

```java
for (var c : "foobar".toCharArray()) {
  switch(c) {
    // Idea error hint here: 
    // Required type: char
    // Provided: Character
    case Character cc when Character.isLetterOrDigit(cc) -> {}
  }
}
```

Comment: For what you show you don't need a pattern match switch at all - just use `if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))`

Comment: The error seems very clear. You provided a `Character` (here: to the method call `isLetterOrDigit`), but a `char`was expected. Have a look at the method's signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JEP455 Primitive Types in Patterns, instanceof, and switch (Preview)

https://openjdk.org/jeps/455

```java
for (var c : "foobar".toCharArray()) {
  switch(c) {
    case char cc when Character.isLetterOrDigit(cc) -> {}
  }
}
```